# How to add a append a value to existing list

Tags: java, arraylist

```
List<Person> people = new ArrayList<Person>();

for (Person p : list) {   
Array person = new array[];   
personList.add(person);   

person.setName(list.getname);  
person.setLastname(list.getLastname);  
person.setAddress(list.address);

people.add(person);
```

In this code my address is having 5 rows and if I have to add bring all these rows in to one

Example, convert this

```
Name        LastName        Address
John        Smith           123
                            LakeViewDrive
                            Wheeling
                            chicago
                            illinois

Scott       Raible          456
                            Discovergateway
                            lakecook road
                            chicago
                            illinois
```

to

```
John        Smith           123 LakeviewDrive Wheeling chicago Illinois
scott       Raible          456 Discovergateway lakecook road chicago Illinois
```

Please let me know how to append address rows to single value with out changing.

Comment: John Smith 123 LakeviewDrive Wheeling chicago Illinois                      scott Raible 456 Discovergateway lakecook road chicago Illinois,,,,,,,, From scott raible in the next line

Comment: What is the data type of address? How did you get output "existing", is it simply printing Person? If yes, maybe your Address has new lines that you should remove.

Comment: What is the `Person` class like?